# do test account accept valid creadit card number (authorize.net)

Tags: authorize.net

i am entering a valid credit card number but it does not accpet it and say invalid creadit card number. and when i enter test cc number it accpet it. Do test account accpect valid creadit card number.

Answer (score 0):

Credit card numbers have a checksum to determine if it is invalid before it is submitted to the bank for verification. A test number has a valid checksum, but is still invalid to the bank.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you read up on the norms regarding the use of credit card numbers, notably [PCI DSS](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/)

So it would be surprising if test accounts would accept real data, as that would be a clear violation of the rules.